# Static variables within Interception class java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, static, ejb, interceptor

I've got a problem which is kinda obvious, though I'm not sure how to solve it.
I've got 2 classes, 1 of which is Interceptor.

```
@Stateless
@Interceptors(AutoId.class)
public class TestClass {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(RepositoryBean.class.getName());

    public void executeUpdate(){
        int k=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 100000; j++) {
                for (int r = 0; r < 1000000; r++) {
                     k = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        getLogger().log(Level.INFO, "Current time some time ago was "+AutoId.MyTime/1000);
        }
    private Logger getLogger() {
        return Logger.getLogger(getClass().getCanonicalName());
    }}
```

and here is Interceptor class:

```
public class AutoId {        
    public static Long MyTime;

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object addLog(InvocationContext context) throws Exception {
        MyTime= System.currentTimeMillis();    
        return context.proceed();    
    }
}
```

an obvious problem is that if I run this application (when it's deployed on a glassfish server) and then in a couple of seconds I run another copy of it, it is going to rewrite MyTime variable with new time and, as a result, both programs will print same time.
One of the obvious solutions is to make a variable inside executeUpdate which will save the value of MyTime, BUT this is not good for the real project I'm working on.

I was told that I might want to do something with ContextResolver and @Context.
Any thoughs on how do I solve this?
Thanks.

**EDIT**
I found one solution, though I don't think it is the best

```
public class AutoId {        
    private static Long[] MyTime = new Long[1000];

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object addLog(InvocationContext context) throws Exception {
        MyTime[(int)Thread.currentThread().getId()]= System.currentTimeMillis();    
        return context.proceed();    
    }

    public static Long MyTime(){
    return MyTime[(int)Thread.currentThread().getId()];
    }
}
```

naming array the same way as procedure allows to minimize code changes in main class only by adding () after AutoId.MyTime -> AutoId.MyTime()

That's still not the best Idea, though it doesn't cause rewriting of variable anymore.

**EDIT2** please don't really mind all the code in executeUpdate() procedure. It is just written in a way it takes some tome to finish working, so that I can execute 1 more copy of it and print out AutoId.MyTime. The value of this variable is the only thing that matters.

Also it's qute obvious that if I wasn't using Interceptor and just created an AutoId variable within class to call it before any other procedure (that's what interceptors for) that error wouldn't appear since every copy of program will have its own id easily - that's not option though. Interceptors are required for autorisation here before executing any procedure. Hope that explains everything I haven't told before :)

Comment: What actually is your requirement to print out this time inside a bean method? Couldn't you to simpy print it out in incterceptor method?

Comment: in the big project there is an ID which is later needs to be used to create an SQL statement, that id you get within interceptor, after trying to log in (that's what happens in normal interceptor I have). If login fails it returns nothing, just an error, otherwise it writes ID of user into that variable and 3 more variables. And interceptor must return context.proceed() so I can't just return the variables. I hope that's clear enough :D

Comment: I think you mix a little bit business logic inside an interceptor functionality. Isn't really possible that you obtain this ID in your business method in different way than a call to a static interceptor field? E.g. retrieve it from DB, from session?

Comment: I mean you can perform an authorisation as it is - in interceptor, but I'm asking if there is an option to retrieve this ID in different way?

Comment: the thing is there is a lot of methods which do certain stuff and they all need authorisation, putting authorisation withing every single one is possible, but that's gonna mess up a big part of already written stuff (not by me, by other people). It was just maid like this and my goal is fix the error with smallest sacrifices possible. I found one solution It's in **EDIT** block. Another is just to store variables instantly after autorisation, though this might not work if 2 calls would happen at once.

Comment: it is in DB and is the return of statement which is called in interceptor, so other than saving that ID somewhere after recieving there is no other option.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `@Produces` for logger creation and use then `@Inject` to inject your logger in your class and interceptor. This way you should log different times.

Comment: you probably got me wrong. There is nothing wrong with logger. Since MyTime variable is static everybody has access to it, it is thus getting rewritten by other thread.